# Divisibility of fourths by seven

Tags: divisibility

I am otherwise very good in mathematics, but recently I came upon a problem that I just can't solve.  Do you have any idea how to solve it?

If $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ is divisible by 7, prove that $a^4 + b^4 + c^4$ is divisible by 7 as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modulo $7$, squares are congruent to $0$, $1$, $2$ or $4$. The only way a trio
of these can add to zero modulo $7$ is for all of them to be $0$, or for them
to be some permutation of $1$, $2$ and $4$. In the latter case, $a^4+b^4+c^4
\equiv 1^2+2^2+4^2\pmod 7$.

Comment: Is that a special, well-known rule that modulo 7 of squares is 0, 1, 2 and 4?

Comment: @Pygmalion I'd say it's well-known, but nothing special.

Comment: @Pygmalion In a problem like this, it should be obvious that it is useful to know and it only takes a couple of minutes to check.  I didn't happen to know that but I hope that I would have found it quickly.

Comment: @badjohn I suspected that there should be something special about divisibility of 7, but I only found another rule that claims that 10*a+b is divisible by 7 if a-2*b is divisible by 7.  Obviously not very useful in this case.

Comment: @Pygmalion In a problem like this, with a small modulus, I would start by just writing out a table of squares.